# Chef recipe use ubuntu environmental variables

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I have a chef recipe which I am looking to utilize the ubuntu environment variables from the system:

```
bash "proj s3 sync" do
  code "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=#{ENV['AWS_ACCESS_ID']} AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=#{ENV['AWS_SECRET']} aws command..."
  cwd     "/home/#{node['deploy']['chef-environment']}"
  user    "#{node['deploy']['chef-environment']}"
  environment ({
    'HOME' => ::Dir.home(node['deploy']['chef-environment']),
    'USER' => node['deploy']['chef-environment'],
  })
  ignore_failure false
end
```

When executing this recipe, the env vars are empty. But from the same machine, doing EG `echo $AWS_ACCESS_ID` returns result as expected.

Is there something wrong with my use of the ruby ENV syntax in this chef recipe? Or another reason the scope of ENV would not possess the properties needed?

Comment: Can you do irb and check `ENV` values?

Comment: yes, values are present from irb

Answer (score 1):

So you are using `ENV` directly there, meaning getting stuff from `chef-client`'s environment. And because `chef-client` is generally run either directly via SSH (without a shell) or as a service (again, no shell) so all your shell initialization files do not get loaded. Remember that Unix has no concept of a "global environment variable" or "system environment variable". You'll want (or need) to use some kind of config file instead.

Comment: hm, but I understood chef recipe bash command was run as `user` defined in recipe, which would have needed environment scope.

Comment: Bash isn't involved, you're using `ENV` and string interpolation which is evaluated by chef-client when the recipe is compiled.

Answer (score 0):

In my context, this implementation was for an AWS server.

AWS offers interface to environment variables for machines managed via opsworks with chef via recipe aws_opsworks_app:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/data-bag-json-app.html